Rotate Border Radius
I want to style the button to look like the first image, but unfortunately, no matter what I try, I can’t round the corners of the image. Only the top-left corner becomes rounded. How can I fix this?
A photo from the site I'm building:

A site I made myself.:



.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hover-image {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease;
}

.image-container:hover .hover-image {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.text-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}

.btn-bottom-right {

  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.bg-banner-btn {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.btn-bottom-right:hover {
  background-color: #424649;
}
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200/800" alt="Your Image" class="hover-image">
  <div class="text-overlay">
    <p class="mute">کت و شلوار زنانه</p>
    <h3>زرق و برق بی انتهای مخصولات تاکسیدو</h3>
    <p class="mute">لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با
      استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-banner-btn">
    <button class="btn-bottom-right">مشاهده و خرید</button>
  </div>
</div>




Welcome! You might consider turning your shared code into an [mcve] (you might just need to set a background height/width/color on the <img/> instead of linking to an external resource; I'm not sure).

I've converted your posted code into a working snippet so that we can see your problem reproduced in your question, of course because you haven't linked to an image available to us we can't see the problem you describe. Can you please [edit] your question, and link to an appropriate image, and also ensure that the snippet accurately reproduces the problem.

https://css-shape.com/inverted-radius/

I doubt this is possible to achieve with border-radius, as that only works for rectangular elements and not arbitrary shapes (concave even). Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ though

"doesn't work in any of my browsers" - which browsers do you have

@Bergi mask is fully supported by all the browsers since one year now (and prefixed since more than 5 years). If you are using old browser use -webkit-mask

@TemaniAfif Oh i see, i was using an outdated chromium. Works in latest Firefox.

I used https://css-shape.com/inverted-radius/ and it partially worked, but one of the corners is still not properly fixed like the other.
